# Running Ionic commands whilst "ionic serve" is running

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

Just getting started with Ionic 2. When i have the app running in NodeJS, I cannot seem to add commands such as "ionic g providers myapi" - I assume these can only be entered when **ionic serve** is not running?

Also previously using Ionic1 I could stop **ionic serve** using quit in the CLI, but there seems to be no way of typing anything when ionic serve is running in the NodeJS console. So I have to currently do a hard close andd re-start the NodeJS application (I am running on Windows 8)

[image]

Comment: CTRL+C will prompt you to close the serve . You can also open another command prompt in the same folder location to run other ionic commands

Comment: how do I open another command prompt from within NodeJS please? No options in right-click

Comment: which env are you running NodeJS?

Comment: Yep, NodeJS version 5.7.1

Comment: I didnt mean within nodeJs..I see you are in windows 8. just open a separate command prompt..traverse to your folder location